# C# - xml-rpc with a single method and 2 named param

Tags: c#, .net, xml-rpc, xmlrpcclient

This is a refined and focused question that I asked last week about a project I am working on to use the web service http://www.upcdatabase.com via xml-rpc .net. I am working in c#.  The request requires a named method (“lookup”) as well as 2 named parameters (“rpc_key”) and (“upc”), both types are stings. My initial thought was to create an interface like this:

```
[XmlRpcUrl("http://www.upcdatabase.com/xmlrpc")]
   public interface UPChelp : IXmlRpcProxy
  [XmlRpcMethod("lookup")]
  upcLookupValues lookupUPC(string rpc_key, string upc);

upcLookupValues is a struct that is returned defined as:
public struct upcLookupValues
    {
        public string upc;
        public int pendingUpdates;
        public string status;
        public string ean;         
        public string issureCountryCode;
        public bool found;
        public string description;
        public string message;
        public string size;
        public string issureCountry;
        public string noCacheAfterUTC;
        public string lastModifiedUTC;
    }
```

The proxy generation I have been working with is

```
UPChelp upcObj = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<UPChelp>();
upcLookupValues myLookup = upcObj.lookupUPC("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000”, "639382000393");
```

I get a response of invalid parameters..  So while reading the xml-rpc faq I came across:

> “2.20 How do I call an XML-RPC method
>   with a variable number of parameters?
>   The params keyword can be used to call
>   an XML-RPC method which take a
>   variable number of parameters. For
>   example, if an XML-RPC method takes a
>   variable number number of integer
>   parameters it could be defined like
>   this: 
>   [XmlRpcUrl("http://www.cookcomputing.com/notimpl.rem")]
>   public interface IParams :
>   IXmlRpcProxy {    [XmlRpcMethod]
>   int UseNumbers(params int[] numbers);
>   }  And called like this:  IFoo proxy =
>   (IFoo)XmlRpcProxyGen.Create(typeof(IFoo));
>   proxy.SendMultipleParameters(1);
>   proxy.SendMultipleParameters(1, 2,
>   3);”
>
> Alternatively the parameters in this
>   example can be supplied as an array of
>   type int[]:  int[] parameters = new
>   int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
>   proxy.SendMultipleParameters(parameters);"

My problem is I don’t understand how to apply this concept to my project, (I am a newbie), I tried upcLookupValues[]  parameters = new string[] { "rpc_key", "upc" };
But I get a cant implicitly convert string[] to readUPC.upcLookupvalues[].  I also don’t understand how to define the new proxy for submission.  My fingers are crossed this post makes sense. I am sure you C# xml-rpc folks are laughing right now.